# Shibboleth Attributes not Mapping

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

We are having an issue with Shibboleth and Apache Server. I am integrating with an SSO portal for a Tomcat application. I have the integration with the SSO portal figured out, but we are having an issue with the mapping of the attributes. We are obtaining a NameID which is the email address. I don’t know what I am missing. I can see the email in the Shibd.log, but I cannot see any attributes in the Shibboleth.sso/Session
Here is my configuration for the attribute-map:

```
<Attributes xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:attribute-map" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" id="persistent-id">
        <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$NameQualifier!$SPNameQualifier!$Name" defaultQualifiers="true"/>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="emailAddress" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" id="emailAddress">
        <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$Name" defaultQualifiers="true" />
    </Attribute>
     <Attribute name="mail" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified" id="mail">
        <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$Name" defaultQualifiers="true" />
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Here is what I have in the Attribute-Policy:

```
<afp:AttributeFilterPolicyGroup
    xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:basic"
    xmlns:saml="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:saml"
    xmlns:basic="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp:mf:basic"
    xmlns:afp="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:afp"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>
        <!-- This policy is in effect in all cases. -->
        <afp:PolicyRequirementRule xsi:type="ANY"/>
        <!-- Catch-all that passes everything else through unmolested. -->
        <afp:AttributeRule attributeID="*" permitAny="true"/>
    </afp:AttributeFilterPolicy>
</afp:AttributeFilterPolicyGroup>
```

The Shibd.log has the following verbiage:

```
019-12-16 16:48:23 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeExtractor.XML : creating mapping for Attribute urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
2019-12-16 16:48:23 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeExtractor.XML : creating mapping for Attribute emailAddress, Format/Namespace:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
2019-12-16 16:48:23 INFO Shibboleth.AttributeExtractor.XML : creating mapping for Attribute mail, Format/Namespace:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified
```

However, as previously mentioned we cannot see any attributes in Shibboleth.sso/Session

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding the attributes:

```
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail" id="SHIB_MAIL"/>
    <Attribute name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" id="SHIB_MAIL"/>
```

This was the only attribute that showed up in the attribute portion of the SP Session.